# Is there a fast way to change tabindexes on a form with lots of controls?

Tags: visual-studio

So I have a form with lots of controls that all have a tab index.

After inserting some extra fields, I have to edit the index of all controls after the new ones.

Is there a simple way to automate this in Visual Studio, or is there some sort of plugin?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a Windows Forms UI. You can click Menu: View | Tab Order, then just click through th controls that you want the tab order to be in. There doesn't appear to be anything similar for web-based UI in Visual Studio.

Comment: wow it revealed that groupboxes are like master to the contained controls, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Make the tabindex's increment by 5 or 10 then if you do insert new controls you dont have this issue.

Answer (score 2):

[MZ-Tools](http://www.mztools.com/) has a [TabIndex Assistant](http://www.mztools.com/v6/features.aspx#TabIndexAssistant).